# Why do individual answers have the option of being community wiki?

Tags: support, community-wiki

I have just seen the check-box for community-wiki for an answer.  For a question, I can understand, but for an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your answer might be something that you want other people to edit and augment. For example, a list of books on a particular topic, or a list of technologies that satisfy a particular niche.

In this case, community wiki is the right option since it lowers the bar for other users to add useful details.

Comment: What happened here? When did you become a blockbuster?

Comment: I might start calling myself *The Moral Voyages of Stephen King (Starmont Studies in Literary Criticism)* http://www.amazon.com/Voyages-Stephen-Starmont-Literary-Criticism/dp/1557420718

Comment: Welbog was always a blockbuster. Guess your city wasn't selected.

Comment: @voyager: I became a blockbuster as soon as Spielberg's surprise announcement that Joel would be playing Jeff.

Comment: @random: in my town, we were lucky we had a broken radio! On a good day! Before it got mugged!

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if you guys notice that I update my profile accordingly with my name. I'm watching my view counter, and I conclude that voyager has **not** looked at it. I expect random has looked, though, based on the timing of the most recent increment.

Comment: You are correct. But it was about an hour ago. And that wasn't the only profile updated.

Comment: @Welbog: normally I read it, but today I forgot to. I'm really hyped to see this movie! What actor gets the privilege to be me? Woody Allen? Am I one of the aliens? You know I am.

Comment: @random: you are sick, even for *my* standards. Anyway, your empirical experiments advance sciense in ways no other human would dare to advance.

Comment: Processed another bottle of drink after the mesmerising experience that is *Steven Spielberg's Welbog*. Will watch again on the blu-ray release. Two thumbs up.

Comment: @Welbog: When will we see all the Welbog merchandise, "Welbog" the video game, and various swag for the movie? We all need our Welbog action figures!

Comment: Chuck Norris isn't in it, so it can't be any good.

Comment: It is best watched it on DVD or BluRay. You really must use **lasers** to get the full effect. Better yet, watch both the DVD and BluRay, that way you get to use **Blue and Red lasers.**

Comment: @Brad Gilbert: You mean **blue and red tiny wizards**, right?

Comment: Umm, can I get a replacement disc somewhere? Apparently when people were talking about using lasers, they were talking about the ones in the player. Whoops.

Comment: @mmyers: doas I do. I watch all my movies with the microwave. Hollywood repeats itself an awful lot.

Answer (score 4):

I've occasionally made answers Community Wiki if they've been improved by many people - e.g. if people have added a variety of comments, and I've edited the answer to include them.

I'd also use CW for an answer which has just culled the best bits of a variety of other answers.

In both cases it leads to a more Wikipedia-like situation: an answer which is genuinely community driven rather than the work of one person, and which becomes the "ultimate" answer to that question.

Answer (score 3):

I tend to make my answer Community Wiki if I feel the question should be CW, and isn't yet.

Comment: Err... why the downvote? Have I been bad?

Comment: @Dominic Rodger: no, simply someone doesn't agree with your behaviour. But you are encouraged to use the system as *you* please.

Answer (score -5):

If you know the community isn't going to like your answer for whatever reason, then you can save yourself some grief by making it CW.

Comment: That's dumb. If it's the right answer and you know the community won't like it, who cares if you shave some digits off of your arbitrary number?

Comment: -1 for being a rep wuss.

Comment: I rest my case.